# Design pattern for calling specific classes that override an especific method

Tags: java, design-patterns, optimization

So I am having a bit of a problem when trying make a class that can be appended subclasses with different functionalities and share a common ancestor without having really big hierarchy trees.

What I am trying to do is make `n` different sub classes of the `Skill` interface which are allocated in a list and then called to be execute. All the in `Skill` are sublclasses of `Event` (not here).

My problem resides in `SkillManager` where I don't how to differentiate which `Skill` it should call and wheter it would be more effect just to create the `Skill` subclass and execute it right then.

This is my Skill.class interface

```
    public abstract class Skill
{
    /**
     * Private shortcut so this code doesn't have to be reused over and over to call
     * for cooldowns on the skills
     * @param dp player making the request
     * @return if the command is available for use
     */
    protected boolean canUse(DPlayer dp){
        String name = "skill_"+getName();
        if(!dp.getTag(name).isPresent())
            return false;
        if(dp.getTag(name).get().getRemaining() > 0) {
            dp.sendActionBarCooldown(ChatColor.AQUA + getName(), dp.getTag(name).get().getRemaining());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Returns the name of this skills, this should also be the same
     * name of the class implementing this interface for initialization
     * propouses
     * @return name of skills
     */
    public abstract String getName();

    /**
     * Executor to be implemented and replace/add functionality
     */
    public abstract void execute();
}
```

This is my SkillManager.class

```
    public class SkillManager
{
    private static final SkillManager instance = new SkillManager();
    private final List<Skill> SKILLS =new ArrayList<>();

    private SkillManager(){}

    public static SkillManager get(){return instance;}
    public void registerSkill(Skill s){
        SKILLS.add(s);
    }
    public void registerSkills(Skill... s){
        for(Skill skill : s){
            SKILLS.add(skill);
        }
    }
    public void unregisterSkill(String name){
        for(Skill skill : SKILLS){
            if(skill.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                SKILLS.remove(skill);
            }
        }
    }
    public void callEvent(Skill skill) {
        skill.execute();
    }

}
```

This is Sneak.class the example implementation

```
public class Sneak extends Skill {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Sneak";
    }

    @Override
    public void onSneak(DPlayer dp, PlayerToggleSneakEvent event){
        if(dp.getTag("skills_sneak").isPresent()){
//DO STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.
EDIT:
The `Event` objects are derived from api calls not from my implementation and contain data about said event
EDIT 2: Adding flow diagram. Red is the parts I coded. Blue is part of the structure I am using
[image: Flow Diagram]

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but in your example there is no need to make `List<Skill> SKILLS` a static member.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheWeis I totally missad that

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues in your OOP code:

- Your `callEvent` doesn't rely on a unique abstract method for all your events implementations, forcing you to check the type of object to call the right method.
- You send a cast of the event instance to itself as a parameter, creating a useless dependency with all your event types in the caller.

Use the *Command Design Pattern*; instead of having `onSneak()`, `onBreak()`, etc, just use a common `execute()` method. In your `Skill.class`, declare execute as abstract method, forcing you to write its implementation in all the extends. It will be used to trigger the event. `callEvent()` now needs just one line of code: `event.execute(dp);`.

You shouldn't send the event to itself as a parameter since, as an instance, it can hold its own properties and is already aware of itself.

*PS:* You call this **optimization** in your question, but this is not really optimization. Fixing the architecture will hardly make your code faster. It will, on the other hand, make it easier to read, maintain, and more reliable. **Beware of premature code optimization.**

Comment: I have made `Skill` so that `execute(SkillCommand)` is abstract. `SkillComand` is a class that encapsulates a `DPlayer` and an `Event` object. However I run into the problem again at `callEvent(SkillCommand)`  where I don't know how to find from the HashMap the correct object(s) I need to call and calling them all would mean all skills executing on 1 player.

Please read my edit I think you missunderstood the `Event` functionality in the code.

Comment: Send all the events to all your Skills, and let the Skills pick up the events they want to handle themselves.

Comment: Would that make each Skill huge?
I edited the code for what I am currently using. Should I just implement the checks on every Skill and each time 1 skill is called actually call 50 more than just do a check and then nothing?

Comment: I'm sorry but since you edit the question everytime you alter the code, I am getting very confused myself. Maybe you should show us what you want to achieve. Draw the events, the players, the skills, what fires them and what outputs from them.

Comment: I added a flow diagram link so you can see what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Access denied. You should upload an image directly in the question.

Comment: Added the flow diagram as picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141452/discussion-between-martinstone-and-guillaume-f).